# my insert statement isn't working

Tags: java, sqlite, servlets

am trying to insert values to the database but it seems there's a problem with the code if anyone can spot it. I am using a Servlet to get the user input and then sending the inputs to the following class using a method:

```
@Override
public String createItem(String title, String info, String url, String imageFilename) {

    String addItem = title;
    Connection conn = null;

    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + DBPath);


        if (conn == null)
        {
            System.err.println("Database connection was null:(");
            return addItem;
        }

        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "INSERT INTO items (title, info, URL, image) VALUES (newtitle, newInfo, newUrl, newImage )";

        //String query = "INSERT INTO items  (title, info, URL, image) VALUES(" + title + "," + info + "," + url  +","+ imageFilename +")";

        stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        stmt.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println("Exception querying database" + e.toString());
    }

    finally
    {
        try
        {
            conn.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        System.err.println("Exception querying database" + e.toString());
        }
    }
    return addItem;
```

}

I have tried to type the values without using the values passed in the method from the servlet.
I have checked my insert Statement in the Sqlite Manager and its working, i also checked if the values were sent to the above class and it is working and i have tried the connection so it is enabling me to retrieve data from it but not inserting to it. so i have no idea why it is not storing the values in the DB.

Comment: What precise symptoms lead you to conclude that "it seems there's a problem with the code"?

Comment: 1- i have tried the connection "to the database" in other methods and it is working with no problems as i used the SELECT statement and i can retrieve data from it.
2-I check if the variables i am passing in the method are working as you can see i am returning on of the values back to the servlet and it is showing " String addItem = title;".

Comment: But you still haven't described any symptoms.  "It doesn't work" isn't a symptom, it's a complaint.

Comment: well i cannot store data to the DB

Comment: What is this supposed to do: `Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");`?

Comment: How are you examining the DB to determine there's nothing in it?  Can you do ANYTHING to the DB?

Comment: Registering the JDBC driver

Comment: yeah i can get data from it using another method, all of my other methods are connecting to the database and retrieving data from it except this one

Comment: And you're sure you're hitting the right table, etc?  (Use sqlite3 command line tool to dump the tables.)  Remember, in many cases SQLite will quietly ignore operations on missing tables, etc.

Comment: well I have a table which contain the follwoing columns: ItemId, Item, Info, URL and Image. i have been asked to do two things:

1- To display every item in the that table.

2- To insert new Items to the same table.

I am able to get data from it but not storing it, so the table DOES exist.

I have used the following statement and it is working:

 String query = "SELECT title from items WHERE item_id =" + itemID;

when i used the same insert STATEMENT in the SQLite Manager it does work

Comment: And is the DB in writable storage?

Comment: And what is the return code from stmt.executeUpdate?

Comment: sorry didnt get that what you mean?

Comment: The return code from executeUpdate?  As in `int executeUpdate(String sql) throws SQLException`, as shown in the spec.  The `int` is a return code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `INSERT` definitely isn't going to work:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO items (title, info, URL, image) VALUES (newtitle, newInfo, newUrl, newImage )";
```

Even if you wanted to store those as string literals, you'd have to use single quotes in the SQL statement like this:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO items (title, info, URL, image) VALUES ('newtitle', 'newInfo', 'newUrl', 'newImage' )";
```

To store the actual values instead of the variable names (which I'm guessing is what you want), use a `PreparedStatement` like this:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO items (title, info, URL, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
);
stmt.setString(1, newtitle);
stmt.setString(2, newInfo);
stmt.setString(3, newUrl);
stmt.setString(4, newtitle);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Doing it this way prevents SQL injection attacks.

Comment: I think it would work.  You only need to use quotes if the value is not a single token.

Comment: do I change the ? to the variable names ???
or only we have the variable names in the setString

Comment: Don't change the question marks, leave them exactly as-is. `setString()` will take care of the rest.

Comment: thank you very much it worked, but is there anyway to get it work with the code i provided ??

Comment: Not exactly sure why you'd want to do it your original way to be honest. More importantly, this way protects you from SQL injection. Read up on that right away if you're unfamiliar with it.